# NHibernate query on one-to-many

Tags: c#, nhibernate, hql

I got a Client entity related to n network domain accounts.

```
Client:
IList<DomainInfo> domainInfo;

DomainInfo:
string domain;
string username;
```

The mapping of Client.hbm.xml contains:

```
<bag name="domainInfo" cascade="all" lazy="false">
  <key column="client"/>
  <one-to-many class="Kardex.CMS.Domain.Model.Client.DomainInfo"/>
</bag>
```

The mappinf of DomainInfo.hbm.xml does NOT contain a many-to-one mapping to Client.

When I insert Client entities with domain info elements into the database, everything works fine. Each domain info entry contains the "client"-column mapped to the right client.

Now I want to query the user with a certain network domain and username:

```
clients = session.CreateQuery("from Client c where c.domainInfo.username = :winuser and c.domainInfo.domain = :windomain")
    .SetParameter("winuser", "john_doe")
    .SetParameter("windomain", "domain123")
    .List<Client>();
```

But I get an exception:

```
illegal attempt to dereference collection [client0_.id.domainInfo] with element 
property reference [username]
```

I also tried an INNER JOIN, but then I get another exception:

```
from Client c inner join c.domainInfo d where d.username = :winuser and d.domain = :windomain
```

throws

```
Could not execute query[SQL: SQL not available]
```

This should be a simple task I guess?
What could be wrong here?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it:

```
select c from Client c left join c.domainInfo d where d.username = :winuser and d.domain = :windomain
```